# Spark cannot find- spark-class-launcher-output-28018.txt

Tags: java, apache-spark

Using Spark1.6.2, win7-64, jdk8, have winutils, HADOOP_HOME.
Have a valid spark setup, can run the examples, start spark-shell, etc
%temp% is correctly setup C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp

> spark-submit --class "com.iot.app.spark.processor.IoTDataProcessor" iot-spark-processor-1.0.0.jar

The **system cannot find** the

```
file C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-class-launcher-output-28018.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with [Permissions on temp folders](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/02/09/resolving-spark-1-6-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-not-found-value-sqlcontext-error-when-running-spark-shell-on-windows-10-64-bit/)

```
List current permissions: %HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe ls \tmp\hive

Set permissions: %HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive

Set permissions: %HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

it's about using

```
""
```

with the class name